# MongoDB Official C# Driver in ASP.NET MVC app with Ninject dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, ninject

Does anyone have a code example that follows best practices of using MongoDB Official C# Driver with Ninject in ASP.NET MVC app?

Mine looks like this:

```
namespace WebApp
{
    public class DataModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            var conventions = new ConventionProfile().SetElementNameConvention(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());
            BsonClassMap.RegisterConventions(conventions, x => true);

            var server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
            var database = server.GetDatabase("webapp");
            Bind<MongoDatabase>().ToConstant(database);
        }
    }
}
```

Since this code is singleton, I have a bad feeling about it :|

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MongoServer is just fine to keep as a singleton.  The same is true of a MongoDatabase.  They are both thread-safe and even if you create a new MongoServer and MongoDatabase every time, you will get back the same instances because they are cached underneath as long as the connection string is exactly the same.